# ensure that all records in Stored Procedures is excute fine

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

please how to ensure that all records in this stored Prodcedures is execute fine, and if insert is not working good dont delete anything .

my Procedure like :
i have to table data and data_archive and i want to insert data into data_archive and after this operation delete my data from table data

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Mybase`@`%` PROCEDURE `archive`()
BEGIN
INSERT `data_archive`
SELECT * FROM `data`;
DELETE FROM `data`;
END
```

this procedure is working fine but i want to ensure dont delete if if the insert did not work
thank you for helps

Comment: *if the insert did not work* ??? The statement cannot "not work". It either is executed successfully or fails. Execute both statements within the transaction, and declare exit handler which rollbacks the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`Mybase`@`%` PROCEDURE `archive`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT `data_archive` SELECT * FROM `data`;
        DELETE FROM `data`;
    COMMIT;
END
```

If both statements are executed successfully then the changes are committed.

If any error occures then the handler rollbacks all changes.

You may add SIGNAL or RESIGNAL statement into the handler for to report to the application that the operation fails.

Comment: there is a problem with this code in line INSERT `data_archive` SELECT * FROM `data`;
probleme is : expect ; , but found insert instead .
whats mean

Comment: just i have a question this procedure work in mariadb too or not ?

Comment: @Azizbouchtaoui must work, test.